# Updating an apps internal data when a live tile changes from a push notification?

Tags: windows-phone, push-notification

I am trying to update a field in my app when its tile is changed.  my main goal is to use push notifications to update data in an app regardless on whether or not the application is running during the time the notification is sent.  So far it seems that it is impossible to get data into an app if the app is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the cloud service you write for push notifications can monitor the send statues of a send notifications.  I have set it up now to send a raw notification and if that notification doesn't go through (because the app isn't running)  it holds onto the message for the user and waits until the user runs the app and makes a connection with the cloud again.